# Assign the value of old column to new column using Django data migration

Tags: django, django-models

I got a problem when I wanted to change a column's type from int to char. But I could't do this directly via Django migrations. so I firstly added a new column and wanted to set its value with the old column's, the SQL is like 'update my_app_myqpp set uuid=id'. How can I do this via Django migrations? Thanks!

```
def migrate_data(apps, schema_editor):
    MyApp = apps.get_model('my_app', 'MyApp')
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    results = MyApp.objects.using(db_alias)
    for result in results:
        result.uuid = str(result.id)
        result.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myq_app', '0002_auto_20150205_0501'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='myapp',
            name='uuid',
            field=api.fields.UuidField(auto_created=True, default='0', editable=False, max_length=32, unique=True, verbose_name='UUID'),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(migrate_data)
    ]
```

I also tried

```
MyApp.objects.raw('UPDATE docker_build_dockerbuild SET uuid=id')
```

but it seemed migrate_data was not performed.

Comment: new updates: the function 'migrate_data' was called, however the data in data was not updated.

Comment: regarding line: result.uuid = str(build.id), where is 'build' defined?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo. it should be result.uuid = str(result.id)

Answer (score 0):

finally I got my problem solved. The way is simple. I separated the migrations to two steps, one was to just add the new field and the other one was to migrate the data. the reason is that '0002_auto_20150205_0501' didn't include the new field. so 'result.save' didn't update the non-exist column 'uuid' even result.uuid was set a value